# is it posible to create a transparent tk window and on it a non-transperent pic, only with tk and PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is it posible to crate a transparent tk window and on it a non-transparent image, only with tk and PIL, or if it's not possible which libary should I use ?
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Fl0.png)

Comment: I know about wx but i cant find an example code for what i need

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', '#abcdef')` to set a specific color to be the transparent color of the window, and then set the window background color to that color.

Below is a sample code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', '#abcdef')
root.config(bg='#abcdef')
root.geometry('400x200')

photo = PhotoImage(file='python.png')
Label(root, image=photo).place(x=50, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

and the result in Windows 10:

[image]

*Updated:*

In order to use transparent image, `Canvas.create_image(..)` can be used:

from tkinter import *

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

transparent_color = '#abcdef'
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', transparent_color)

canvas = Canvas(root, bg=transparent_color)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
photo = PhotoImage(file='python-logo.png')
canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=photo, anchor=N+W)

root.mainloop()
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: i tryed that but my image is also with trasperant background but it shows as white back ground

Comment: @j.doe See my updated answer using `Canvas.create_image(...)` to draw image with transparent background.